# name does not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What am I doing wrong? At Start() the GameObject gets instantiated and saved in `_blockedMatter`. After clicking on a specific field the objects should get destroyed but I get an error

> Error CS0103: The name '_blockedMatter' does not exist in the current context

So it does not get saved there?

```
void Start()
{
    ...
    GameObject _blockedMatter = (GameObject)Instantiate(buildmanager.blockedMatter, GetBuildPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
    ...
}
...

public void unlock()
{
    ...
    Destroy(_blockedMatter);
    ...
}
```

But why does this work then?

```
...
GameObject _cleaningEffect = (GameObject)Instantiate(buildmanager.cleaningEffect, GetBuildPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
Destroy(_cleaningEffect, 5f);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first block of code, the scope of `_blockedMatter` is only confined to the `Start()` method and hence it throws an error when trying to access it in a different method. Hence, make the variable `_blockMatter` accessible in the entire class by declaring it globally and accessing or setting it's value in the `Start` method

```cs
GameObject _blockedMatter;

void Start()
{
    _blockedMatter = (GameObject)Instantiate(buildmanager.blockedMatter, GetBuildPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

In the second block of code, the variable is within the scope of the method in which it is accessed and hence it doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 1):

It's just about the scope of the variables. the variable has scope within the method in which they are defined.

In the first case, you are trying to access `_blockedMatter` outside the method Start. But in the second case, you are accessing `_cleaningEffect`  in the same method.